# Change Nimbus ProgressBar for one Component

Tags: java, jprogressbar, nimbus

I try to change the default color of the nimbus JProgressBar. I can change the color global by change the "nimbusOrange". I like that result. But I need one ProgressBar in original nimbusOrange by nimbus and another ProgressBar included in the same program with blue-color. I try this:

```java
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

UIDefaults overrides = new UIDefaults();
overrides.put("nimbusOrange", Color.BLUE);
overrides.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].backgroundPainter", UIManager.get("ProgressBar[Enabled].backgroundPainter"));
//overrides.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter", UIManager.get("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter"));
progressBar.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides);
progressBar.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
```

But if I put the foregroundPainter back to the code it shows just the normal orange style of the ProgressBar...

Any Help?

Kind Regards
Highchiller

Comment: So the question is, how can I change the "nimbusOrange" color for only one component...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution but it looks like a pretty hard hack... If anyone knows an easier way to solve it, please tell me.

I take the original [ProgressBarPainter.java](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc6/src-html/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus/ProgressBarPainter.html) which extends the AbstractRegionPainter. I change the name to BlueProgressBarPainter. Also it gets a PaintContext object in the constructor. This class is a protected inner-class of AbstractRegionPainter. So I change the given parameter to Object and cast it in the constructor.

After all the constructor looks like:

```java
public BlueProgressBarPainter(Object ctx, int state) {
    super();
    this.state = state;
    this.ctx = (AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext)ctx;
}
```

Also we change all access of "nimbusOrange" to "internalBlue" and add this new color (for instance BLUE) to nimbus and the line before we introduce the new LookAndFeel:

```
UIManager.put("internalBlue", Color.BLUE);
```

Ok... so good as well.
Now we have to add our own painter to the specific progressBar. But we need the AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext object of the original painter. To get this, we need reflection! Cause the method "getPaintContext()" from the AbstractRegionPainter is protected.

```
    // initialize progressBar
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    // create own UIDefaults
    UIDefaults overrides = new UIDefaults();
    BlueProgressBarPainter painter = null;

    // get the original AbstractRegionPainter of Nimbus
    AbstractRegionPainter abstractPainter = (AbstractRegionPainter)UIManager.get("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter");

    // reflection begin
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = abstractPainter.getClass();
        // get the protected Method of AbstractRegionPainter
        Method protectedMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getPaintContext");
        protectedMethod.setAccessible(true);

        // create now our own Painter with the original AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext
        painter = new BlueProgressBarPainter( 
                (Object) protectedMethod.invoke(abstractPainter) ,
                3 ); // 3 is constant for "FOREGROUND_ENABLED"
    } catch (Exception e) {} 

    // set original background painter
    overrides.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].backgroundPainter", UIManager.get("ProgressBar[Enabled].backgroundPainter"));
    // set own foreground painter
    overrides.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter", painter);
    // accept overrides
    progressBar.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", overrides);
    progressBar.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
```

This is pretty hard i think... but it works o.O wuhu.

Best regards,
Highchiller